# How to query 2 tables relation of which is described by another pk to pk table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB of 3 tables: `categories`, `items`, `relation`. `categories` contain categories. Goods are stored in `items` and `relation` is a binding table, it stores the product id and category id or categories.

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I for a given list of items, get the names of all categories?

Comment: Simply `JOIN` the tables.

Comment: Seems a simple inner join between the tree tables

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @etsa Not w3schools please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try simply `LEFT JOIN` like this.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    items AS i
LEFT JOIN relation AS r ON i.id = r.id_items
LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON r.id_cat = c.id
```

Hope this helps.

Above query will give you all the items which are note even mapped in the relation table While below query will give you only those items which has defined the relation in table relation

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    items AS i
RIGHT JOIN relation AS r ON i.id = r.id_items
LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON r.id_cat = c.id
```

Let me know if you get any error.

Answer (score 3):

Just join them:

```
SELECT *
FROM relation r
INNER JOIN items i ON r.id_items = i.id
INNER JOIN categories c ON r.id_cat = c.id
```

Note that an INNER JOIN will only select the records that show up in both tables. The * here selects all columns. If don't want all of them, you can select the ones you want like this: i.id, i.name, c.id, c.name, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct(c.name) from categories c
JOIN relation as r on c.id = r.id_cat
JOIN items as c on i.id = r.id_items
WHERE i.id in (8, x, y, z, ...etc)
```